# Preg match for all phone numbers starting with 07045

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

I'm trying to add some code that prevents a form entry if the phone number starts with 07405. I've tried the following with no such luck, any ideas?

HTML field:

```
        <input type="tel" name="required[phone]" placeholder="Telephone Number" data-required="strict">
```

PHP:

```
  case 'phone';

           $phone = (sanitize_text_field($fields['phone']));
          if (preg_match('07045', $phone))
          {

            $fields['valid_phone'] = $phone;
            unset($fields['phone']);
          }
          else
          {
            unset($fields['phone']);
            array_push($errors, 'phone');
          }
          break;
```

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: You definitely didn't read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot delimiters at preg_match, and beginning of string (you try to match substring in whole string).

```
preg_match('~^07045~', $phone)
```

The second thing is that regex isn't necessary for this task, substr will be faster.

```
if (substr($phone, 0, 5) == '07045')
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with substr as suggested and works like a dream.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
preg_match('/^07045/',$phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) for this, to avoid regex:

```
if ( strpos( $phone, '07045' ) === 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this check at client side using javascript or jQuery.
For php use,
preg_match('/^07405/',(string)$phone)